# if dynamic rnn trained to output with variable size input then how to test it on input

Tags: recurrent-neural-network

Consider this scenario -
Suppose number of output classes is nine each denoting a specific word say
(1)a
(2)use
(3)hold
(4)civil
(5)hardly
(6)vitamin
(7)determine
(8)housewives
(9)infuriation
We gave multiple wav file of each word as input (padded with zeroes if its duration is less than 1 second) to RNN and associated corresponding one hot vector with it.
So, RNN has learnt to output class label after every second.
Now , i give it a second of test input containing word 'a' and 'use'.
Question 1) Will output of RNN be a vector containing two ones ?
Quesition 2)Is it possible to determine the intermediate step at which specific word was detected ?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1) It may, it may now. The network might get confused. Especially so, if the test input contains these words closely following each other. Hence, the waveform will be affected by coarticulation and the individual words might not get recognized.
2) If you mean specific time on the wave, then I suppose it is possible but you'd have to adjust your training to that. It's very unlikely it will learn this task from the task defined in your question.

Comment: if I had only word 'one' in test input but at different position than in training then would RNN show one hot vector for 'one' as output after one second ?
i am guessing yes . else RNN would be useless .

Comment: Theoretically, yes. It may show you when the word ended (unless you employ bidirectional RNN or reverse the waveform -- then it can show where it starts). But to achieve that, you have to provide dataset from which it is possible to learn the timing. Personally, I think the model will have low accuracy. You might have more luck with a spectrogram than a raw waveform.